# Internal Error?

Tags: package-management, error-handling

I've never asked a question here before so bear with me. I'm running 13.04 and whenever I run my package manager it doesn't fully execute because it comes up with an error saying it can't open my cache and says that my packages have unmet dependencies. I do not know if my cache doesn't exist or what to do exactly. I'd like to just update to 13.10 but it won't let me run the package manager and I am not able to do so manually. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Namaste

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) question

Go through the first answer. Once your problem of "unmet dependencies" is solved you will be able to complete the update process!

Hope this helps!